# How to set a radiobutton as checked by updating its FormControl

Tags: angular

In my app I have a Component which acts as a radio-button-group and in it I have my own radio-button-components. I use FormGroup on the radio-button-group and formControlName on each radio-button-component. When I set the FormControl's value the radio-button doesn't get checked. How can I accomplish this in the best possible way?

Link to my stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dmkmed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass formGroup to the child and there get the value of control you want, or simply pass selectedValue. Then you use [checked] attribute and compare value and selectedValue, then it will work.

Here is working demo on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xnxusf)